# Tag Merge request for the-legend-of-heroes

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, retag-request

Merge request for [the-legend-of-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-legend-of-heroes) to [loh-trails-in-the-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loh-trails-in-the-sky)

The legend of heroes tag is already part of the "loh" part of the individual games that have tags on them. There is no need for it.

Comment: Given the tag length increase to would it be more suitable to use [legend-of-heroes-trails-in-the-sky] (34 chars) instead?

Comment: @Robotnik Oh yeah totally I forgot about the increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags have been merged to [legend-of-heroes-trails-in-the-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-heroes-trails-in-the-sky)

However, given that 'Legend of Heroes' could refer to any of the LoH games in the series I opted not to create a synonym for that tag.