# Rename [trails-in-the-sky-fc] to [legend-of-heroes-trails-in-the-sky]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I'd like to propose renaming the tag for The Legend of Heroes: Trails in the Sky from [trails-in-the-sky-fc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-in-the-sky-fc) to [legend-of-heroes-trails-in-the-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-heroes-trails-in-the-sky).

The FC title was apparently only used for the Japanese release. There was talk of [lengthening the tag in the past](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12586/merge-request-for-the-legend-of-heroes?rq=1#comment40321_12586), but it never seems to have happened.

Answer (score 2):

Renamed to [legend-of-heroes-trails-in-the-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-heroes-trails-in-the-sky) and made the former tag a synonym.